# AntTweakBar not appearing on ATI graphics based hardware

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, ati

I'm currently working on a project for my 3rd year at University using OpenGL with GLEW, GLFW and AntTweakBar. On my own machine (i5-2500k, GTX 570) it runs fine. However, when I've tried it on a number of other systems (all of which have ATI graphics) I can only either get the actual rendering to show, or the AntTweakBars.

To make it a bit clearer, on my own machine I initialize AntTweakBar using the line:

```
TwInit(TW_OPENGL, NULL);
```

Which works fine. Now, on the other computers I've tried it on at the University, if I keep this line the same, the AntTweakBars fail to appear but my own renderings do appear. However if I change that line to:

```
TwInit(TW_OPENGL_CORE, NULL);
```

The tweak bars appear, but my own rendering disappears. I may be jumping to the conclusion of it being related to the ATI graphics but I don't have access to another nvidia based machine to test on. 
So, has anybody experienced anything similar to this or have any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you doing the integration correctly? Nobody can know what the problem is without seeing your code.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong somewhere. I've managed to repeat the problem on my own computer now using `glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)`
Also as for integration, I just call `TwInit(...)` at the start of the program, after initializing GLFW and GLEW. Then I create all my bars, Then I call `TwDraw()` after doing my rendering and just before the call to `glfwSwapBuffers();`